# Making 5 mysql queries into 1

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I have mysql table with columns `id`, `pos` and `status`.
And I need to swap `pos` value of exact `id` with the nearest smaller `pos` value. But I need to count only rows with `status = 1`.
In other words it should work like this:

```
$pos = mysql_result(mysql_query("select pos from foo where id = $id"),0);
$min = mysql_result(mysql_query("select min(pos) from foo where status = 1"),0);
if($pos != $min){
  $i = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT pos from foo where pos < $pos ORDER by pos DESC LIMIT 1"),0);
  mysql_query("update tbc_sidebar set pos = $i where id = $id");
  mysql_query("update tbc_sidebar set pos = pos + 1 where id <> $id AND pos = $i");
}
```

It works just fine like this, but I think it's not the best solution to have 5 queries because of one simple thing. Is there any way how to put it all into less queries? Thanks!

Comment: It works, it's simple, why complicate things?

Answer (score 1):

There are two thing you can do: use a **stored procedure** <sup>[[1]](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-procedure.html)</sup> <sup>[[2]](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-stored-procedures/)</sup> or send multiple queries at once with [**transaction**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php). It kinda depends on which side you want to keep it all.

Also , i would strongly recommend for you to drop the old `mysql_*` functions as a way of accessing MySQL database. They are more then 10 years old, not maintained anymore and the community has begun the [process of deprecation](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). You should not write new code with `mysql_*` in 2012. Instead you should learn how to use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) as the API for accessing DB.

Here are two tutorials you might look at:

- [PDO Tutorial for MySQL Developers](http://wiki.hashphp.org/-PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)
- [Introduction to PHP PDO](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this but it should work. It is not pretty!

```
UPDATE tbc_sidebar main
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT t1.id id1, t1.pos pos1, t2.id id2, t2.pos pos2
    FROM tbc_sidebar t1
    INNER JOIN tbc_sidebar t2
        ON t1.pos > t2.pos
        AND t2.status = 1
    WHERE t1.id = $id
    ORDER BY t2.pos DESC
    LIMIT 1
) AS tmp
    ON main.id = tmp.id1 OR main.id = tmp.id2
SET main.pos = CASE
        WHEN main.id = tmp.id1 THEN tmp.pos2
        WHEN main.id = tmp.id2 THEN tmp.pos1
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Store procedure is a best choice to execute multiple queries together.